# How can I cancel LoadAsync() without closing the underlying socket?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have an app that communicates to some hardware over rfcomm on bluetooth.  My app works on Android and am in the process of getting things working on UWP. Here's how I set up the stream reader/writers in the UWP code:

```
var btDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(devId);

var services = await btDevice.GetRfcommServicesAsync();

if (services.Services.Count > 0)
{
    // We only have one service so use the first one...
    var service = services.Services[0];
    // Create a stream...
    _bluetoothStream = new StreamSocket();
    await _bluetoothStream.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);

    _dataReader = new DataReader(_bluetoothStream.InputStream);
    _dataWriter = new DataWriter(_bluetoothStream.OutputStream);

    _dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
```

My hardware only sends data to my app after the app sends it data so I've set up a send/receive mechanism.  Everything works great except for a specific use case where my device is restarting (but bluetooth connection is still active) and is unable to send a response.  In this case my upper level code is setup to attempt a retry, however the bluetooth connection gets closed when the receive times out.

```
_dataWriter.WriteBytes(comm.TransmitData);

Task<UInt32> writeAysncTask = _dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask();

UInt32 bytesWritten = await writeAysncTask;
:
try
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(comm.TimeoutMs))) // _receiveTimeoutMs)))
    {
        // When this times out, exception gets thrown and socket is closed
        // How do I prevent the socket from closing so I can do a retry???
        var loadTask = _dataReader.LoadAsync(comm.ReceiveCount).AsTask(cts.Token);

        bytesRead = await loadTask;

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            rxData = new byte[bytesRead];
            _dataReader.ReadBytes(rxData);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received 0!");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // The bluetooth connection is closed automatically if the
    // caancellationToken fires...In my case, I need the connection
    // to stay open...How do I achieve this???


    // Update: When this code is executed with _dataReader/Writer
    // that was created with SerialDevice class (see below), the
    // timeout exception does not cause the Serial connection to
    // close so my calling code can then issue a retry.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message) ;
}
```

UPDATE:  It should be noted that when I use the exact same code with streams created from a SerialDevice everything works as I would expect...When the receive times out the socket is NOT closed.  Seems like maybe I'm up against something in the Bluetooth Implementation in UWP.  Ugh.  Here's how I create the _dataReader/_dataWriter with the SerialDevice class:

```
_serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(devId);
// Configure the port
_serialDevice.BaudRate = _baudrate;
_serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
_serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
_serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;

_dataReader = new DataReader(_serialDevice.InputStream);
_dataWriter = new DataWriter(_serialDevice.OutputStream);
```

Comment: so do you mean have a SerialDevice which connected with the app using Bluetooth and it works well when you restart it?

Comment: Roy,  Yes, when I map my bluetooth device to a comm port and create the _dataReader/_dataWriter streams with the SerialDevice class, the connection is not closed when the LoadAsync times out.  My calling code can then issue a retry which will succeed.  I will update the code in my question with more comments to clarify this more.

Comment: Got that. Which type is the hardware that the issue happens? According to previous post, it's an android device?

Comment: The device is custom hardware with a BT121 chip from Silicon Labs.  My Android reference was referring the Android version of my app which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a work around to the problem I was facing.  Unfortunately, I can't use the same code for SerialDevice and BluetoothDevice.  I have to say, it really stinks that the bluetooth socket gets closed when a cancellation token times out.  The code would be so much cleaner if it didn't close!  Shouldn't it be up to me to decide if the socket should be closed?  Now I'm stuck with this:

```
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)comm.TimeoutMs, cts.Token);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Canceling async read");
                // If we make it this far, then the read as failed...cancel the async io
                // which will cause the bytesRead below to be 0.
                await _bluetoothStream.CancelIOAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }, cts.Token);

        var loadTask = _dataReader.LoadAsync(comm.ReceiveCount).AsTask();

        bytesRead = await loadTask;

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // SIgnal the delay task to cancel...
            cts.Cancel(true);
            if (bytesRead > comm.ReceiveCount)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received too much!!");

            rxData = new byte[bytesRead];
            _dataReader.ReadBytes(rxData);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received 0!");
        }
    }
```

After implementing this, I did notice that after I've paired my BT device, Windows returns it as a SerialDevice in the following query:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
// My bluetooth device is included in the 'devices' collection
```

So if I connect to it as a serial device, I guess I won't need the work around after all.  Oh well, hopefully this post will help someone else.